# How to move focus to previous element from textbox in wpf?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have a sample UI and trying to move focus to previous element on pressing Key Up. Can someone help me how to move focus to previous textbox from current Textbox or another elements.

Here is my Sample UI

```
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample_Application"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <DockPanel PreviewKeyDown="DockPanel_PreviewKeyDown" PreviewKeyUp="DockPanel_PreviewKeyUp" KeyUp="DockPanel_KeyUp" >
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="18,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="18,8,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="18,8,0,0" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="18,8,0,0"  Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="18,8,0,0"  Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="18,8,0,0"  Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,34,0,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>

Below is my code behind

        private void DockPanel_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Up && e.OriginalSource is TextBox)
            {
                FocusNavigationDirection focusDirection = FocusNavigationDirection.Previous;
                TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(focusDirection);
                UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;

                // Change keyboard focus.
                if (elementWithFocus != null)
                {
                    if (elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(request)) e.Handled = true;
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Your code should work. You can even compact it by removing redundant code: 1) cast `sender` parameter to `FrameworkElement` to get the focused element (the current `TextBox` the user is typing to) and remove the `Keyboard.FocusedElement` part and the related null checks 2) Don't mark the event as handled. It's best practice to only mark it as handled if you have a very good reason to do so, e.g. delegating the event to a different event. Marking a preview event as handled will also cancel the bubbling version.

Comment: 3) It also seems to be redundant to handle PreviewKeyUp and KeyUp.

Comment: Do you understand that `e.Key == Key.Up` filters for the arrow up key (and does not represent a key state)?